# Building, and Publishing, and User-Data (oh my!)

Tags: c#, .net, build-process, publishing

**What is the best way to update a "Web-Application" ("re-publish" from dev server to live server) while preserving user-data (such as images, videos, and audio stored in the filesystem) in a VS 2010 build/publish setup?**

Additionally, what is the best way to minimize site downtime during these updates?

---

My backstory:

Usually I "build/publish" the site to a folder on my dev machine, ftp:// into the live server, then drag-and-drop the new "published" files and folders to the live site while making sure not to overwrite any user-generated directories.

Obviously this method comes from my static-html days where it didn't matter. And obviously this is dangerous, flawed, and counter-productive for any Web Application with user-generated data in the FS.

Comment: What's the origin of the phrase X, Y and Z (oh my!)?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=x,+y,+z+oh+my - top result.

Comment: Sorry, I left out an "and". I was referring to the Wizard of Oz.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was just me who turned it into algebra so I never Googled for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to have a directory that's outside of your code folder where you store the user data. You can even map this folder as a virtual folder in IIS when you need this folder to be available from the internet. Like:

```
C:\Inetpub
    \ProjectWebsite
    \ProjectFiles
```

Comment: Hm, I like this. Are there any hurdles regarding permissions (beyond allowing read/write access to the .net service) with this approach?

Comment: If you set the permissions correctly like you normally do for IIS accessable folders, you should be totally fine.